# X509 CRL suspended certificates and openssl ca comand

Tags: certificates, openssl, crl

In CRL X509 format we have "Hold Instruction code" for a list of suspended certificates. I know that "its use is strongly deprecated for the Internet PKI", but in my own private CA, I want to use it.

Openssl has a `ca` command where I can do all the "ca" stuff direct on my linux cli. It has an option `-crl_hold instruction` to put "on hold" a certificate, but how can I remove the "on hold" status of this certificate? I haven't found any way to manage the temporary suspension of this certs.

Any help will be very helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [*OpenVPN 2 Cookbook*](https://books.google.com/books?id=lwDyCHPzd7oC&pg=PT256&lpg=PT256&dq="Each+line+that+starts+with+an+%27+R+%27+is+added+to+the+CRL"&source=bl&ots=M8TIqhGKmN&sig=lowdhLbO1bpfzs45Q99Mpg0fQhg&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwik6YCRhb7MAhWMApoKHcoDDDkQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=%22Each%20line%20that%20starts%20with%20an%20'%20R%20'%20is%20added%20to%20the%20CRL%22&f=false):

> The OpenSSL `ca` command generates its CRL by looking at the 
>   index.txt file. Each line that starts with an ' R ' is added to the
>   CRL, after which the CRL is cryptographically signed using the  CA
>   private key.

To reinstate your revoked certificate, you could edit [your CA database](https://pki-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cadb.html):

```
database       = $dir/index.txt        # index file.
```

1. Update the relevant entry in `$dir/index.txt`, by replacing `R=revoked` with `V=valid`.
2. Recreate the crl file: `openssl ca -gencrl ***`
3. What's left is the automation of the process (*A script?*)

Comment: I am using a HSM, do not have access to the DB. I thought that could exist a command in openssl to  unsuspend the certificate. But you answer was the best one til now.

Answer (score 3):

There is no method to "unsuspend" a certificate in openssl on the CLI that I am aware of. And the following quote may give you a bit more guidance:

Martin Abalea, OpenSSL mailing list, 2008-10-13, [*Re: Put certificate on hold*](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.encryption.openssl.user/31961/focus=31962):

> Reading the X.509 recommendation (downloadable for free from the ITU-T
>   web site) tells us that a certificate can be "un-holded" by 2 means:
>    - either really revoke it, by changing the reason code while keeping    the date
>    - or completely remove it from the CRL, as you guessed.

Again, I am not aware of any CLI commands for OpenSSL so your options may be:

1. issue a new cert or
2. restore a copy of the CA DB prior to the revocation and issue a new CRL.

   If you have other revoked certs, you want to make sure you jot them down if you restore your DB. Otherwise, you stated this is your private CA, I don't see why generating a new CERT is an issue.

   There is yet a "long shot" method you may be able to using Microsoft (don't know how to do something similar in OpenSSL).
3. If you can import your cert into the MS CA, MS has an easy "right click" to unrevoke. [See the following](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739815%28WS.10%29.aspx) documentation on how to do this. Here is the CLI from that page:

   > To unrevoke a certificate revoked with the reason code "Certificate
   >   Hold," at a command prompt on the CA, type:

   ```
   certutil -revoke CertificateSerialNumber unrevoke
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Reading the X.509 recommendation tells us that a certificate can be "un-holded" by 2 means:

- either really revoke it, by changing the reason code while keeping 
  the date
- or completely remove it from the CRL. 
  If you plan to issue deltaCRLs, you MUST use the "removeFromCRL" 
  reason code for such certificates, only for the deltaCRLs.